# Problem with representation of a xsd complexType in SOAP WebService

Tags: java, web-services, soap, xsd

I am trying to implement a SOAP webservice with java.
I have the following .xsd complexType definitions:

```
<xsd:complexType name="BasicURL">
   <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Generic representation of an URL with a possible user-friendly label</xsd:documentation>
   </xsd:annotation>
   <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
         <xsd:attribute name="label" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:extension>
   </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="URL">
   <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Extended representation of a URL with possible language and fee</xsd:documentation>
   </xsd:annotation>
   <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="BasicURL">
         <xsd:attribute name="lang" type="Language"/>
         <xsd:attribute name="fee" type="BasicAmount"/>
         <xsd:attribute name="currency" type="Currency"/>
      </xsd:extension>
   </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The generated java classes look like this:

```
public class BasicURL {
   protected java.lang.String value;
   protected java.lang.String label;

   public BasicURL() {
   }

   ...

}
```

and

```
public class URL extends BasicURL  {
   private Language lang;
   private BasicAmount fee;
   private Currency currency;

   public URL() {
   }

   ...
}
```

I then have a method that returns a ComplexValue, defined as

```
<xsd:complexType name="ComplexValue">
   <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Represent a value taking the form of a basic type, a list of values or a table of values</xsd:documentation>
   </xsd:annotation>
   <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:element name="boolean" type="xsd:boolean"/>
      <xsd:element name="number" type="xsd:long"/>
      <xsd:element name="text" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:date"/>
      <xsd:element name="dateTime" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
      <xsd:element name="url" type="gen:URL"/>
   </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

with the following java generated class

```
public class ComplexValue  {
   private java.lang.Boolean _boolean;
   private java.lang.Long number;
   private java.lang.String text;
   private java.util.Date date;
   private java.util.Calendar dateTime;
   private URL url;

   public ComplexValue() {
   }

   ...

}
```

If I then initialize and return the ComplexValue like so:

```
...

URL url = new URL();
url.setLabel("Google");
url.setValue("http://google.com");
url.setLang(new Language("en"));
url.setFee(new BasicAmount("14.00"));
url.setCurrency(new Currency("USD"));

ComplexValue value = new ComplexValue();
value.setURL(url);

return value;
```

I get the following tag-representation of that element:

```
<ns15:complexValue>
   <ns16:boolean />
   <ns17:number />
   <ns18:text />
   <ns20:date />
   <ns22:dateTime />
   <ns25:url lang="en" fee="14.00" currency="USD" />
</ns15:complexValue>
```

Notice how it only shows the attributes defined in the URL type, and completely omits the attribute (label) and element (http://google.com) of the BasicURL type? Why is that, and how can I figure out the problem?

Edit:
I should add that other complexTypes, like for example Court

```
<xsd:complexType name="Court">
   <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="webSite" type="gen:BasicURL" minOccurs="0"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:attribute name="cdbId" type="xsd:token"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

with a java class of

```
public class Court  {
   private java.lang.String name;
   private BasicURL webSite;

   public Court() {
   }

   ...

}
```

do produce a correct tag

```
BasicURL url = new BasicURL();
url.setLabel("click here")
url.setValue("http://somesite.com");

Court court = new Court();
court.setName("somecourt");
court.setURL(url);

return court;

...

<ns12:court>
   <ns12:name>somecourt</ns12:name>
   <ns12:webSite label="click here">http://somesite.com</ns12:webSite>
</ns12:court>
```

Comment: What SOAP library are you using? Seems the code at runtime is missing some meta-data. These days I would have expected the meta-data about things like `<xsd:choice>` to be given as annotations on the class, but it could be given by other means, e.g. an accompanying text file. If it is a text file and you forgot to deploy it, the library would default that class as `<xsd:sequence>`, which could well result in what you see, since all the elements are mandatory (again, missing meta-data).

Comment: @Andreas: the problem isn't the empty tags (boolean, number, text, ...).
it's the url tag that's missing the label attribute and its value even though the url clearly extends basicurl

Comment: The empty tags are a problem, since the generated XML violates the XML schema. Both are an indication of something going wrong. Since I don't know what, don't even know which SOAP library you're using, I was theorizing what that something might be.

Comment: @Andreas: Sorry for being flippant, I'm rather new to working with web services. I generate the code through IBM Domino Designer. I guess I should have mentioned that somewhere.